# Example of a filesystem available to Linux that does not guarantee a `read()` after `write()` returns what has been written?

Tags: linux, filesystems

The [Linux write() man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html) says:

> POSIX requires that a read(2) that can be proved to occur after a
> write() has returned will return the new data.  Note that not all
> filesystems are POSIX conforming.

I think it refers to the [POSIX write() page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html), which says:

> After a write() to a regular file has successfully returned:
>
> - Any successful read() from each byte position in the file that was modified by that write shall return the data specified by the write() for that position until such byte positions are again modified.
> - Any subsequent successful write() to the same byte position in the file shall overwrite that file data.

Is there an example filesystem available to Linux that does not conform to this rule?

Comment: The general example of a filesystem that can't meet all POSIX requirements is NFS because there's no way to keep local caches synchronized across all clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `/proc/` is an obvious one:

```
$ echo hello > /proc/564769/comm
$ cat /proc/564769/comm 
hello

$
```

(it added an extra newline)

2. NFS: if a client calls `write()` but not `fsync()`, and the server crashes and restarts, the next `read()` from the client will return the old data.
   Note that while neither POSIX nor the Linux man pages qualify their statements, they all assume that the app (client-side, in this case) doesn't crash between the write and the read, but say nothing about the storage medium (server-side, in this case).
3. FUSE: FUSE supports writeback-cached mode, so any filesystem that uses it will be susceptible to the same issue as the NFS server crash above, where the FUSE daemon can crash.
   Moreover, anyone can write a FUSE filesystem that just has a non-POSIX semantics in the same way that procfs does.